# How do I stream internal audio from Windows 7 to Android for free?

Tags: audio, streaming

The audio jack is busted so I want to stream the internal sound to my Android phone and use my headset on that phone instead. No, not just music files. I mean the whole internal sound coming from the laptop. That includes error sounds, clicking sounds (if any) the recycle bin being emptied, etc. Isn't there anything other than Airfoil that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SoundWire Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.georgie.SoundWireFree) appears to do this...but the free version has limitations:

> The free version of the application identifies itself by voice every 30 minutes and displays ads. The full version can handle up to 10 connections at the same time, and has no ads or voice identification. Please consider purchasing the full version of SoundWire if you'd like to support the developer.

Edit to add:
That page has [SpeakerShare](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speakershare) in the "others viewed" links, which appears to be an open source app to do the same thing. The lone comment mentions it's delayed (likely due to buffering/network latency), but things like videos can be worked around (VLC offers an audio synchronization option, for example).

Comment: SoundWire seemed to work okay. Thanks! :) I hope there's an mac version too.